# Render to Vulkan Image from one process, display image in a different process, working without semaphores. Why?

Tags: c++, c, vulkan

I successfully have two separate vulkan processes, which are completely separate applications, sharing a piece of external image memory. One of the processes is rendering into the external image memory from a renderpass. Then the other process is displaying that external image memory on quad.

This just works. With all validation layers enabled. No errors. No glitches. Which sounds great I presume?

Issue is, I absolutely did not expect this to just work, I don't understand why. I thought I would need to make external semaphores to synchronize the read and write to this external image memory from the different process, but it just works without that?

I've been perusing all the Vulkan spec for something to explicitly state why this seems to work fine with no additional synchronization abstraction. But the spec can still confuse me quite a bit.

The most I've gathered is that it seems like read and write operations do carry a degree of atomicity on images, even across processes. Is that true? So, you can just set two different processes to read write as fast as possible, and they don't corrupt each other?

If that were true, I'd expect to maybe get image tearing, or v-sync tearing, down the image if their rendering loops became offset. But weirdly enough, I do not see that either. So, is the texture load op and texture read op for an entire pipeline stage atomic as well?

Or is this a scenario where just by mere chance of how this thing is currently set up, it's working by pure luck?

*edit*

How I am creating the external texture:
https://github.com/rygo6/Fabric-OVR-Vulkan/blob/f818452dc507ef554d2b723f410a350bc1226e01/src/fbr_texture.c#L143

How I am loading in the external texture:
https://github.com/rygo6/Fabric-OVR-Vulkan/blob/f818452dc507ef554d2b723f410a350bc1226e01/src/fbr_texture.c#L49

How I am creating the framebuffer:
https://github.com/rygo6/Fabric-OVR-Vulkan/blob/f818452dc507ef554d2b723f410a350bc1226e01/src/fbr_framebuffer.c#L67

Comment: Sounds like pure luck to me, or at least relying on something platform specific.  To provide anything more specific would need to see more detail on how you set this up, and how the external image was allocated.

Comment: I added some github links to the methods I am using. So typically, I would need to be using external semaphores to do this?